# Evaluating eigenvectors using Lapack?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a non-symmetric matrix $
L=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & r_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\
0 & -(r_1+g_1) & r_2 & 0 &0 & \cdots \\
0 & g_1 & -(r_2+g_2) & r_3 & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
$ and I need to accurately compute the eigenvalues and left-right eigenvectors of this matrix. I know that one of the eigenvalues is 0 (by construction of $L$) and the corresponding right eigenvector $\phi^R_0 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$. The left eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue should be flat, i.e., all entries should be the same $\phi_0^L = \begin{pmatrix}c \\ c\\ c\\ c\\ \vdots\end{pmatrix}$, where the $c$ will be determined via the orthonormalization condition $(\phi_0^L,\phi^R_0) = 1$. The problem I face is that Lapack doesn't give me a flat left-eigenvector. The numbers are off by a huge factor. I currently use ZGEEV to diagonalize this matrix. Two (probably) important things to note:

- $g_n \gg r_n$ making the upper diagonal much smaller than the lower diagonal. If $r_n \approx O(1)$ then $g_n \approx O(10^3)$
- The first entire column of the matrix $L$ is 0.

Any suggestions on how to accurately obtain the eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Comment: ZHEEV works only for hermitian matrices. You should use DGEES and DTREVC instead.

Comment: Sorry its ZGEEV. It was a type. Corrected now :D

Comment: In this case everything should be OK. Is there only one zero eigenvalue? Does the left eigenvector $v_0$ associated with zero eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ returned by ZGEEV is a valid left eigenvector? What is the norm $\|v_0^HL - \lambda_0v_0^H\|_2/\|L\|_2$? It should be close to eps.

Comment: I haven't checked the norm but the left eigenvector is definitely not a valid eigenvector. As I mentioned the matrix L is constructed in such a way that the left eigenvector should be flat. That is NOT the case with ZGEEV.

Comment: But if everything is correct, then ZGEEV returned estimation of left eigenvector associated with zero eigenvalue, just different than expected. Such situation is possible if: 1. there is a coding error, 2. distance between zero eigenvalue and the closest eigenvalue is small, or 3. error of computed eigenvalue/eigenvector pair is large and computed eigenvector is inaccurate.

Comment: I do believe coding error can be ruled out. The distance between 0 and the closest eigenvector is not small rather large. 3 could be probable but would like to correct it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If (3) is correct, then you cannot do anything. It means, that the problem is highly sensitive to perturbations and eigenvectors cannot be computed accurately. To tell more about this problem you should give: 1. condition numbers for zero eigenvalue and computed eigenvector as returned by ZGEEVX (and explained in ZTRSNA), 2. the backward error estimator given as $\|v_0^HL - \lambda_0 v_0^H\|_2/\|L\|_2$, 3. the norm $\|L\|_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random matrices with such structure have the following properties:

1. there is one exact zero eigenvalue.
2. there is one eigenvalue very close to zero with forward error $|\lambda - \hat{\lambda}| \leq 10^{-11}$.
3. all other eigevalues are much higher, of order O(1) to O(1000)

In this case computing and interpreting single left and right eigenvectors makes little sense; they may change dramaticaly when the matrix is slightly perturbed. Only two dimensional invariant subspaces can be computed reriably.

Both returned left eigenvector are valid eigenvectors, they belongs to the eigenspace associated with the zero eigenvalue. These eigenvectors can be different than the one computed analytically and they are.